# Filter post by current user ID in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am using the plugin [Post View Stats](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/post-views-stats/) I want to be able to display table to with the statistics of my individual post (with date range filter). The plugin already provides a table but I would like to filter posts published by the current logged user in order to provide some statistics to my authors.

First part to select the date

```
if( !defined('ABSPATH') ) die('-1');
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "cn_track_post";
if(isset($_POST['to']) and isset($_POST['from'])) {
    $select = "SELECT *,count(*) as counts FROM $table_name WHERE create_date >='".$_POST['from']."' AND create_date<='".$_POST['to']."' group by post_id order by counts desc LIMIT 0,100";
} else {
    $select = "SELECT *,count(*) as counts FROM $table_name WHERE 1 group by post_id order by counts desc LIMIT 0,100";
}
$tabledata = $wpdb->get_results($select);
```

Second part to display each post

```
$i=1;
foreach($tabledata as $data) { 
$posts = get_post($data->post_id); 
$title = $posts->post_title;
$user_info = get_userdata($posts->post_author);
```

Database structure : cn_track_post

id / post_id / created_at / create_date

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO " . $table_name . "( post_id, created_at, create_date ) VALUES (" . $post->ID . ",'" . time() . "','" . date('Y-m-d')."')";
```

Comment: I only have this : 
id / post_id / created_at / create_date (I am using a plugin)

Comment: No, I think, it's a new row in cn_track_post

Comment: Is it ok like this ?